# Is repeatedly setting window scroll handler OK?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scroll handler function which I'm setting (with jQuery) thus:

```
$(window).scroll(windowScrollHandler);
```

I make an AJAX call periodically which brings in new HTML and after this, the scroll handler function no longer works properly. So what I've done is to run the above line of code after every time I make the AJAX call, and it all seems to work OK now, in early testing. I'm wondering, though, whether this has some implications for memory, like I'm stacking up handlers or something, and whether I need to clear the existing handler first (with 'off'). Or does this 'scroll' function simply replace the existing handler function with a new one? I.e., there can only ever be one scroll handler function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlers should stack. It seems odd to me that the scroll handler would stop working after your AJAX call, given that the handler is on the window, not on an element that would be replaced after the AJAX call. Regardless, I think the best practice would be to remove the old handlers before adding new ones.